# How to add month range in datetime picker in MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

I am developing MVC app with razor.
I am using date picker in it. 
I want to show previous 15 days and next 15 days should be enabled to choose.
(I should able to choose date between 13 May to 13 june)

Which paramenter should I add in below code ?

```
 $(function () {
            $('#DueDate').datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd-M-y",
                minDate:"Now",
                yearRange:"2011:2013",
                showWeek: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showOn: "button",
                buttonImage: '@Url.Content("~/Resource/Calender.jpg")',
                buttonImageOnly: true
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the minDate and maxDate properties as explained here: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate

```
minDate: '-15d',
maxDate: '+15d'
```